# Excel VBA, refresh data on opening if not refreshed today already

Tags: excel, refresh, pivot-table, vba

I have an excel spreadsheet that uses pivot tables.

Currently I have a hyperlink to refresh the data which is new each day.

I would like to develop a method of refreshing the data on opening the Excel file, but not it it has already been updated today.

Is this possible using VBA?

My current code is...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
        If Target.Range.Address = "$A$1" Then

            MsgBox "Your data will now be updated.  This may take a moment..."
            ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
            Sheet1.Range("A2").Value = DateTime.Now

            Exit Sub
        End If

    End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put your code in `Workbook_Open`

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/265113